# Spark Length in Air vs. DC Voltage

Tags: electrostatics, lightning

How can I calculate the potential difference (in DC) needed to create an electric spark of a specific length (between 0-5mm) in air? The sparks are observed between 2.5cm metal spheres. Is there a formula?

Comment: Formula for spark? Neither have I heard of any such formula, nor do I think there is one.

Comment: Officially the breakdown field for air is 32MV/m, so 32KV would jump 1mm. In practice this drops a lot with any dust, moisture etc in the air so for safety assume at least 10x less than this

Comment: your answer is probably in the field of high-voltage engineering, where issues like this must be dealt with every day. Try posting on the engineering stack exchange.

Comment: Look up the Paschen formula (or the Paschen curve). But, as noted in other comments, you will need to control the atmosphere to get reproducible results.

Answer (score 5):

According to 80 year old knowledge (but I guess it doesn't matter in this case) it is about 30 kV/cm when spherical electrodes are big compared to spark length, and in the ballpark of 10 kV/cm when electrodes are needles.

[image]

More info: http://www.kronjaeger.com/hv/hv/msr/spk/

Answer (score 3):

There are several sources quoting that air breakdown is approximately 30kV/cm, but I have also seen 10kV/cm. This also depends on the shape of your electrodes (large spheres vs. needle points, and what is in your air (humidity, etc).